# How to convert python str to bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 and I need to convert return value of `struct.pack()` function (which is `str` according to docs) to a `bytearray` object. `bytearray()` builtin function accepts a string value, but docs say I also **must** pass an `encoding` parameter to be used to encode the string to bytes. I don't know what that encoding should be since the `struct.pack()` return value presumably should already be in byte values, It's not an actual text string, so there is no encoding.

So how can I turn a `bytes` object stored in a Python2 `str` into a `bytearray` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: the documentation has been [corrected](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/0c75819f1d86); you don't need to use the encoding parameter when passing in a string, the section now correctly tells you that is only needed for `unicode` objects.

My old answer follows below.

---

The documentation is wrong; it was copied wholesale from Python 3 where the encoding parameter is indeed required as the (unicode) string has to be encoded to bytes first.

On Python 2, just pass in the string, with no encoding specified:

```
>>> bytearray('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
bytearray(b'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
```

and mentally replace *string* in the documentation with *`unicode` string*.

I've filed a new [issue in the Python tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue22575) to have this corrected.

Comment: Fixed.  The sentence now reads "If it is unicode, you must also give the encoding (and optionally, errors) parameters; bytearray() then converts the unicode to bytes using unicode.encode()."

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: Thanks for the speedy documentation fix!

Comment: I try to do any easy doc fixes when the Friday new issues list comes out, lest they get lost and sit for years.  Suggested plain-text (unformatted) rewordings in tracker messages are welcome.